# Changepoint detection and forecasting

Tags: forecasting, change-point

I am seeking to develop a three-staged algorithm that should be able to detect change in

1. Mean
2. Variance
3. Both Mean and Variance simultaneously if they exist.

I would be glad if this program can also produce a forecast for the series. MLE is popping up as suggested by some authors but I really need further documentation and theory to get through with this. I also want to consider if wavelets can be of help in this direction. Any guidance on this?

Comment: While not directly answering the question, perhaps this article can provide you with some ideas. https://www.casact.org/abstract/survey-approaches-changepoint-problem-actuarial-context

Answer (score 0):

One useful way of accomplishing this could be to implement a Bayesian Switchpoint Analysis model using the tensorflow_probability library - which builds on work already done using pymc3. The relevant documentation is available here: [Bayesian Switchpoint Analysis](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Bayesian_Switchpoint_Analysis)

In the provided example, the Hamiltonian Monte Carlo method (a type of Markov chain Monte Carlo method) is being used to generate posterior distributions for the series both before and after the switchpoint. By a posterior distribution, we mean a distribution that is based on an updating of the prior probability after gathering data relevant to the problem at hand.

The algorithm can detect whether the mean, variance or periodicity changed significantly at a particular point by creating a posterior distribution for the data before and after the switchpoint - this is done by generating many random samples that account for uncertainty in the posterior distribution. By detecting differences between these distributions, the switchpoint can be more accurately identified.

You might also find these references of use:

- [Detecting Conversion Change Using Bayesian Change Point](https://artofmarketingscience.github.io/detecting-conversion-changes-using-bayesian-change-point/)
- [Bayes for Beginners: Probability and Likelihood](https://www.psychologicalscience.org/observer/bayes-for-beginners-probability-and-likelihood)
- [Detect Change Points with Bayesian Inference and PyMC3](https://towardsdatascience.com/detect-change-points-with-bayesian-inference-and-pymc3-3b4f3ae6b9bb)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there are many methods that can achieve this.  If you are wanting to adopt an assumed model form e.g., mean structure with covariates and seasonality, then you can identify changes within the data and use the last segment to forecast the series forward (usually assuming no further changepoints).  This [paper (open access)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qre.2712) discusses the pros and cons of adding changepoints at different model-building stages.

If you are wanting to detect departures away from an assumed model (either mean or variance/dependence structure) then [this talk](https://youtu.be/n-rThN8ktT4) may be helpful.

The author of both of these, Rebecca Killick, has also published papers using wavelets to identify changepoints, a couple of links below.  You could reach out to them for help with your question too.  There are a small number of researchers looking at changepoints and wavelets, these include, from the UK, Haeran Cho, Piotr Fryzlewicz and Idris Eckley.

- [Changes in variance using wavelets](https://doi.org/10.1002/env.2576)
- [Changes in variance and/or covariance using wavelets](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/13-EJS799)
- [Changes in mean with potentially nonstationary errors](https://doi.org/10.1002/sta4.351)